# How to edit a rendered HTML page in Python Jupyter?

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, jupyter-notebook

I am using jupyter notebook in this project. Right now the implementation of my code is strictly based from an API called OSMnx. A graph I needed directly renders an .html page folium.

However, I wanted to edit that .html page and add another element. How can I do this?

```
graph = ox.plot_graph_folium(makati, popup_attribute = 'name',edge_width=2)

filepath = 'graph.html' #<-- this is the html page where *graph* is saved
graph.save(filepath)
IFrame(filepath, width=600, height=500) #<-- renders to jupyter
```

Where part of the html body only contains this:

```
<body>    

        <div class="folium-map" id="map_c37c729e86d64119aec19e0055a1ab04" >
        </div>  
        #I want to add a button element here
</body>
```

- How can I access filepath?
- How can I edit it and add another element (with the existing?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> How can I access filepath?

Since your filepath is `'graph.html'`, you are simply saving this HTML file to the working directory where your Jupyter notebook is located.

> How can I edit it and add another element?

To edit the HTML file, open it in any text editor. You may add in HTML elements as you normally would.

Comment: hi! surprised that the creator is the one replying. Yeah actually I just did that. But I'm wondering if pythonically could there be a way. Thing is, the graph generation might be requested again within the program hence overriding it unless I pythonically create a function that upon a button click, the elements I want to add will be appended over the folium (like graph_route_folium). Those elements would be the nodes and instead of finding nx.shortestpath for routes, I want it based on the nodes that I will select from the folium. Hence my need to do it at the back-end. Any ideas?